# add specific URL to shortcut target C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Trying to create a few different shortcuts to various URLS on a Desktop with the following method:

```
public static void CreateShortcutWithURL(
    string shortcutName, string shortcutPath, string targetFileLocation)
{
    var shortcutLocation = Path.Combine(shortcutPath, shortcutName + ".lnk");
    var shell = new WshShell();
    var shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutLocation);

    // The description of the shortcut
    //shortcut.Description = "My shortcut description";

    // The icon of the shortcut
    //shortcut.IconLocation = @"c:\myicon.ico";

    // The path of the file that will launch when the shortcut is run
    shortcut.TargetPath = $" \" {targetFileLocation} \" https://www.somewebsite.com";

    shortcut.Save();
}
```

It errors out if I try adding anything to the `targetFileLocation`.

I use it like this:

```
CreateShortcutWithURL(
    "My Shortcut",
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
```

If I change this line in the method to this it completes without error:

```
shortcut.TargetPath = targetFileLocation ;
```

The shortcut is put on the desktop - but without the additional https://www.somewebsite.com added to the target - so it just opens the browser without directing it to the website.

I'm trying to create a few shortcuts that open explorer, but make it navigate to particular websites.

Comment: target path shouldnt start with a space... What are you really trying to put in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things are wrong:

1. You don't need `""` around the path to iexplore.exe
2. You can't add the website address to the path, it must be an argument

Change the following code:

```
shortcut.TargetPath =" \" "+targetFileLocation+ " \" " + " https://www.somewebsite.com" ;
```

To this:

```
shortcut.TargetPath = targetFileLocation;
shortcut.Arguments = @"https://www.google.com";
```

The rest of the method is fine as it is.

Comment: Unfortunately I see this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in MyApp.exe

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: Hey that worked great! I didn't realize there was an arguments piece - doh.

Thanks a ton!